# getting error as The "path" argument must be of type string, Received undefined

Tags: visualstudiocode, visual

In Trailhead Challenges In Build a Bear-Tracking App with Lightning Web Components project, I have completed the challenge but it's not working for deploy source to org. I am getting an error as The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined.

Please help me with this ASAP.

Regards,
Harshini